# Need to know what bike I have the serial # is LP9 0246 badge # is 0589

Tags: identify-this-bike, schwinn

I believe I have a 1978 Schwinn cruiser the serial number is on the bottom of the Frame and it reads just like this LP9 0246 and the badge number is 0589 can someone tell me what I have?

[image: Close-up of the underside of the bottom bracket of a red bicycle showing the serial number LP9 0246]

Comment: https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/1978.html

Comment: What problem do you have that is so important that you need to know.  If you have a problem, best describe the problem.  Its very rare that the make and model is important.

Comment: It is important to me this was supposed to be my fathers bike and he worked At the Schwinn plant in Chicago until they moved to ms and he left this w my uncle and I’ve never met my dad so I’m trying to find out what’s true and what’s not thank you

Comment: And also I posted it on a website for vintage Schwinn people to see if they knew anything about it and two guys only said something and they said it’s not a ‘78 and it’s from 88 or 89 and if that’s true then it can’t be my fathers c

Comment: I googled to a side that decodes serial numbers and it indicated 1978.

Answer (score 2):

That serial number is consistent with a Schwinn frame produced in Chicago in November 1978. The numbers on the headbadge refer to the 58th day of 1979, which presumably was when the full bike was assembled, so it was probably a 1979 model.

You can find old Schwinn catalogs online at Bikehistory.org, so I suggest you look through the 1979 catalog and see if your bike matches any models there.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Vintage Schwinn serial number lookup page](https://bikehistory.org/serial-number.html) your bike was made in 1978.
Assuming the bike is

- all original
- it has 26" wheels
- the parts match the picture in the catalog...

In 1978 Schwinn made three 26" wheel cantilever models:

- Spitfire -26" x 2.125" tires
- Heavy-Duti - 26" x 1 3/4" tires
- Typhoon - 26" x 1 3/4" tires

Based on the

- cantalever frame
- chain ring style
- year

[Your bike would be a Spitfire](https://bikehistory.org/catalogs/1978.html) The Spitfire is the red bike on the right with circles in the chain ring rather than triangles.
[image]
When I googled "1978 schwinn spitfire" all the bikes I found in the wild had chain rings that matched your bike.

What troubles me is that the bike in question seems (it's hard to tell in the picture) to have narrower tires than 26" x 2.125". As old as the bike is narrower tires could have been installed. The Typhoon had narrower tires stock but the chain ring does not match.
[image]
When I googled "1978 schwinn typhoon" none of the bikes I found in the wild had chain rings that matched your bike. They all had chainrings that matched the catalog.

I'm going with "Spitfire" final answer.